# Angularjs adding callback after controller has been loaded from outside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

Is it possible to add a callback to be called *after* a controller has been loaded in angular? I want to listen such an event from **outside** that controller however!

I'm integrating our application with an existing angular application and I don't want to modify its source files. To that end I need to be able to take loaded controllers and enhance their scopes with custom functionality. However many controllers are not loaded on application start and thus I need to be able to intercept them right after they have been loaded (right after a specific view has been loaded for example) and run the modifications.

How can I achieve that, without changing *any* of the source files. All changes and listeners must be added from third party code.

Example code:

awesome.js:

```
awesomeApp.controller('AwesomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.awesomeFunction = function...
}]);
```

punyIntegration.js

```
(function() {
  $rootScope.$on('awesomeControllerHasBeenLoaded', function(controller) {
    controller.scope.punyFunction = function...
  });
})();
```

Comment: Angularjs or Angular2? Please also add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: what it says on the title

Comment: Then the tags should at least say the same ;-) Tags should not be repeated in the title though.

Comment: I have to attract people with angular backgrounds thus I used the generic angular tag

Comment: That's not what tags are for.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer done. Please remove downvote

Comment: That wasn't me. Sorry, can't remove other peoples downvotes ;-) I'm not the only one monitoring the Angular tags :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By listening to the `$viewContentLoaded` event you can achieve such functionality. However to do this on any page and not on a specific view, you have to listen via the `$rootScope` like so:

```
$rootScope.$on("$viewContentLoaded", function($event, data) {
  //at this point the view has been loaded
  //and you have access to its scope (i.e the controller's scope)
  //via angular.element(any selector).scope()
});
```